# How to query for a pattern in a DB table with HTML content in the particular column ?

Tags: regex, database

We have a table called with a column which is purely HTML. I need to do a find a pattern like [4digit max]_[6digit number]. Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by the 'max' in '4digit max'? You mention 'DB' in your question title and 'database' in the tags, but are you trying to do the regex using the database syntax? In that case, what sort of database is it, mySQL? We need more information!

Comment: Is `4digit max` 0 to 4 digits or 1 to 4 digits?

Comment: We are using SQL Server Studio - Provided by Microsoft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Microsoft SQL Server, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx):

```
select * from Notif_Template
where dbo.regexMatch( Notif_body, '([^0-9]|^)[0-9]{1,4}_[0-9]{6}([^0-9]|$)' ) = 1;
```

`dbo.regexMatch` returns if there's a match and 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't say wich database, here is a way to do it with PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('abc1234_123456xyz', '(?:[^0-9]|^)([0-9]{1,4}_[0-9]{6})(?:[^0-9]|$)');

  substring
-------------
 1234_123456
(1 row)
```